# Convert IP address (IPv4) itno an Integer in R

Tags: mysql, r, ip, ip-address, bit

I was looking for a way to write a function in R which converts an IP address into an integer.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
total  IP
626    189.14.153.147
510    67.201.11.8
509    64.22.53.140
483    180.9.85.10
403    98.8.136.126
391    64.06.187.68
```

I export this data from mysql database. I have a query where i can convert an IP address into an integer in mysql:

```
mysql> select CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('75.19.168.155', '.', 1), '.', -1) << 24 AS UNSIGNED) + CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('75.19.168.155', '.', 2), '.', -1) << 16 AS UNSIGNED) + CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('75.19.168.155', '.', 3), '.', -1) << 8 AS UNSIGNED) + CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('75.19.168.155', '.', 4), '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED) FINAL;
```

But I want to do this conversion in R, any help would be awesome

Comment: Why not use [`INET6_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton) / [`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and then just raw integer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were not entirely specific about what conversion you wanted, so I multiplied the decimal values by what I thought might appropriate (thinking the three digit items were actually digit equivalents in "base 256" numbers then redisplayed in base 10). If you wanted the order of the locations to be reversed, as I have seen suggested elsewhere, you would reverse the indexing of 'vals' in both solutions

```
 convIP <- function(IP) { vals <- read.table(text=as.character(IP), sep=".")
               return( vals[1] + 256*vals[2] + 256^2*vals[3] + 256^3*vals[4]) }

> convIP(dat$IP)
          V1
1 2476281533
2  134990147
3 2352289344
4  173345204
5 2122844258
6 1153107520
```

(It's usually better IT practice to specify what you think to be the correct answer so testing can be done. Bertelson's comment above would be faster and implicitly uses 1000, 1000^2 and 1000^3 as the factors.)

I am taking a crack at simplifying the code but fear that the need to use `Reduce("+", ...)` may make it more complex. You cannot use `sum` because it is not vectorized.

```
 convIP <- function(IP) { vals <- read.table(text=as.character(IP), sep=".")
                return( Reduce("+", vals*256^(3:0))) }

> convIP(dat$IP)
[1] 5737849088    5112017 2717938944    1245449 3925902848   16449610
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what i wanted and I pologize for not being clear. Essentially this was my main objective convIP <- function(IP) { vals <- read.table(text=as.character(IP), sep=".")
+                          return( 256^3*vals[1] + 256^2*vals[2] + 256*vals[3] + vals[4]) }

Comment: Ooops. I guess I reversed the ordering of the multiplication.

Comment: But I dont understand how Bertelsen's command would work ? @IShouldBuyABoat

Comment: He would convert 1.1.0.1 to 1101. So you're right. It wouldn't actually work to deliver a unique value unless he expanded the numbers with fewer than 3 decimal places to the proper number of leading 0's. And even with that mod it would have a lot of gaps in  resulting values as well.

Comment: Thanks for the Reduce code, I could use that for something else @IShouldBuyABoat