# Converting IP Addresses in R

Tags: r, ip, ip-address

I have a dataset (dat) of IP addresses, which are formatted like this:

```
Person     IP_Address
 267      555.66.44.222
 299      111.222.55.22
 513      222.111.8.777
 524      888.88.333.222
```

I also have a database (db) of IP addresses, which are formatted like this:

```
First_IP_Address_In_Netblock    Last_IP_Address_In_Netblock     Latitude    Longitude
        16777216                        16777471               -27.48333    153.01667
        16777472                        16778239                26.06139    119.30611
        16778240                        16779263               -37.814      144.96332
        16779264                        16781311                23.11667    113.25
        16781312                        16785407                35.689506   139.6917
        16785408                        16793599                23.11667    113.25
        16793600                        16797695                34.38528    132.45528
        16797696                        16798719                35.689506   139.6917
        16798720                        16799743                34.38528    132.45528
        16799744                        16799999                35.689506   139.6917
```

My question is twofold:
1) how can I convert the IP addresses (from either the dataset or the database), so that they're in the same format?
and 2) how can I match up each person with their latitude and longitude?  This second issue is stumping me because each coordinate is associated with a range of IP addresses (from the first IP address in the netblock to the last IP address in the netblock), rather than a single address.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610147/convert-ip-address-ipv4-itno-an-integer-in-r) for converting the IP address to an integer. Then you just need to look by range because IP address are usually assigned in blocks so they share a location.

Comment: Also, it doesn't help that your example IP addresses aren't valid IP address. Each number should be between 0-255.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my `iptools` package (https://gitlab.dds.ec/bob.rudis/iptools) I have an `ip2long` function that does a very vast conversion of IPv4 strings to long integers. It's Rcpp-based and needs Boost headers. The following is a pure-R implementation:

```
ip2long <- function(ip) {
  # convert string into vector of characters
  parts <- unlist(strsplit(ip, '.', fixed=TRUE))
  # set up a function to bit-shift, then "OR" the octets
  octets <- function(x,y) bitOr(bitShiftL(x, 8), y)
  # Reduce applys a funcution cumulatively left to right
  Reduce(octets, as.integer(parts))
}
```

NOTE: That needs the `bitops` package.

You can then convert the IP addresses to long integers and check to see if it's between the First & Last IP netblock addresses. i.e. something like:

```
library(data.table)
library(bitops)


ip2long <- function(ip) {
  # convert string into vector of characters
  parts <- unlist(strsplit(ip, '.', fixed=TRUE))
  # set up a function to bit-shift, then "OR" the octets
  octets <- function(x,y) bitOr(bitShiftL(x, 8), y)
  # Reduce applys a funcution cumulatively left to right
  Reduce(octets, as.integer(parts))
}

# i added the 1.0.0.2 entry to show you the result 

dat <- read.table(text="Person     IP_Address
 267      555.66.44.222
 299      111.222.55.22
 513      222.111.8.777
 555      1.0.0.2
 524      888.88.333.222", stringsAs=FALSE, header=TRUE)

lookup <- read.table(text="First_IP_Address_In_Netblock    Last_IP_Address_In_Netblock     Latitude    Longitude
        16777216                        16777471               -27.48333    153.01667
        16777472                        16778239                26.06139    119.30611
        16778240                        16779263               -37.814      144.96332
        16779264                        16781311                23.11667    113.25
        16781312                        16785407                35.689506   139.6917
        16785408                        16793599                23.11667    113.25
        16793600                        16797695                34.38528    132.45528
        16797696                        16798719                35.689506   139.6917
        16798720                        16799743                34.38528    132.45528
        16799744                        16799999                35.689506   139.6917", stringsAs=FALSE, header=TRUE)



rbindlist(lapply(dat$IP_Address, function(ip) {

  ip_long <- ip2long(ip)

  res <- lookup[ip_long>=lookup$First_IP_Address_In_Netblock & 
                ip_long<=lookup$Last_IP_Address_In_Netblock, c(3,4)]

  if (nrow(res) > 0) {
     return(data.table(ip=ip, res))
  } else {
    return(data.table(ip=ip))
  }

}), fill=TRUE)


##                ip  Latitude Longitude
## 1:  555.66.44.222        NA        NA
## 2:  111.222.55.22        NA        NA
## 3:  222.111.8.777        NA        NA
## 4:        1.0.0.2 -27.48333  153.0167
## 5: 888.88.333.222        NA        NA
```

I'm using `data.table`'s `rbindlist` since it has a nice `fill` option that fills in missing columns.

I have an older MaxMind pure R package: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/Rmaxmind : that can help here, and the Rcpp-based `iptools` package I mentioned above also can do geolocation of IPv4 addresses.

If you try to use the code in this answer, I highly recommend storing your lookup table as a `data.table` as it will be significantly more efficient (and there are ways of speeding up the queries there, too). You could also store the lookup table in a SQL database and use smart indexing and query optimization to do the lookups that way.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response!!  When I run the code as is I get the following error message: `Error in rbindlist(lapply(dat$IP_address, function(ip) { : 
  unused argument (fill = TRUE)`  I removed `fill=TRUE` and got the following error message: `Error in strsplit(ip, ".", fixed = TRUE) : non-character argument`  Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: Load the latest data.table from CRAN or github. The "fill" parameter is recent.

Comment: I believe I have the most recent version installed (1.9.2)...

Comment: Nope. 1.9.4 is latest CRAN and github